# XPath compare node attributes

Tags: xpath

I have a xml document presenting as such:

```
<foo>
  <bar a="first">
        <baz b="test"  c="x">
        </baz>
  </bar>
  <bar a="second">
        <baz b="test" c="y">
        </baz>
  </bar>
  <bar a="third">
        <baz b="noTest" c="y">
        </baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

And I would like to select all "bar" nodes for which there exist 2 different baz subnodes where the value of b is identical but the value of c is different.
So, in the above example, I'd like to select the first two nodes, but not the third.

Here's my attempt:

//bar[baz/@b=following-sibling::bar/baz/@b and baz/@c!=following-sibling::bar/baz/@c]

My problem is that while that works on the example, it does not do what I want: it selects the node if there exists another baz node for which bar/@b has the same value and if there exists another baz node for which bar/@c has a different value; not if there exists another baz node for which both bar/@b is the same and bar/@c is different.

Is it possible to combine both conditions so that they check on the SAME following sibling?

Comment: I think that it is not possible in XPath 1.0, unless the matching `bar` nodes will be adjacent? if so, you could use `//bar[baz[(following::bar[1]/baz/@b = @b and following::bar[1]/baz/@c != @c) or (preceding::bar[1]/baz/@b = @b and preceding::bar[1]/baz/@c != @c)]]`